# Reduce height and width of 3 bars inside Font Awsome Hamburger

Tags: font-awesome, hamburger-menu

I want to make slim to 3 bars inside Hamburger. These 3 bars look fat when I apply "fa-2x".

Using code `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>`

[image: Current Hamburger]

Answer (score 0):

You can suscribe to pro licence to have acces to icon light style or you can use a custom svg.

**[Solid (free):](https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars?style=solid)**

[image]

**[Light (pro):](https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars?style=light)**

[image]

**Custom thin icon menu example**

```js
var faSplat = {
  prefix: 'fac',
  iconName: 'bars',
  icon: [
    448, 448, [],
    null,
    'M442 114H5a5 5 0 0 1-5-5V84a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h435a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v24a5 5 0 0 1-5 5zm0 160H5a5 5 0 0 1-5-5v-24a5 5 0 0 1 5-6h435a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v24a5 5 0 0 1-5 5zm0 160H5a5 5 0 0 1-5-5v-24a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h435a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v24a5 5 0 0 1-5 5z'
  ]
}

FontAwesome.library.add(faSplat)
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js"></script>

<i class="fac fa-bars fa-2x"></i>

<br/>
<br/>


<div style="background-color : black; padding: 10px">
  <i class="fac fa-bars fa-2x fa-inverse"></i>
</div>
```

More information about custom icons in fontawesome : https://github.com/mlwilkerson/fa-custom-icon-demo